# Inverted lookup table with tolerance in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to solve the following problem in python. I can use one set of files to create a unique mapping `id -> (value1, value2)` ie. given an integer get a set of 2 double values. In a second set of files I can get a similar set of `(value1, value2)` and want to know to which id from the first mapping this set corresponds to.

My approach so far was to create a dict from the first set of files and invert it. Unfortunately, the sets are not exactly equal so a simple lookup in the inverted dictionary  fails. So what I need is something like given `(value1, value2)` return the id corresponding to `(value1', value2')` where `|value1 - value1'| < eps` and `|value2 - value2'| < eps`. I don't know if something like this can be implemented with dictionaries or if there is a better way to do so.

Real life example:
my inverted dictionary:

```
{(9.734898e+18, 59.66132): 0,
 (3.337931e+18, 64.06269): 1,
 (5.31014e+18, 62.91672): 2}
```

input: `(5.310139904e+18, 62.916717841490154)`, expetected result: `2`

Edit: here is my attempt in code:

```
>>> d = {(9.734898e+18, 59.66132): 0, (3.337931e+18, 64.06269): 1, (5.31014e+18, 62.91672): 2}
>>> inv_d = {v: k for k, v in d.items()}
>>> test = (5.310139904e+18, 62.916717841490154)
>>> inv_d[test]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: (5.310139904e+18, 62.916717841490154)
```

I could of course simply loop over all items in the dictionary and check my condition manually like this:

```
def is_close(v1, v2, eps):
    return np.abs(v1 - v2)/v1 < eps


def find_id_in_dict(d, search_key):
    result = []
    for k, v in d.items():
        if is_close(k[0], search_key[0], 1e-6) and is_close(k[1], search_key[1], 1e-6):
            result.append(v)

    if len(result) != 1:
        raise Exception("fail")

    return result[0]

test = (5.310139904e+18, 62.916717841490154)
print(find_id_in_dict(d, test)) # yields 2
```

I was looking for a more elegant solution than this. It should not happen that multiple entries match the critera, so best would be to throw an exception in such a case.

Comment: You forgot to post your attempt to solve this problem.

Comment: What if multiple entries meet this non-exact criteria?

Comment: thanks for your question. I edited my question to provide additional information

Comment: Your "attempt" in no way tries to handle the "fuzzy matching" you are asking for.  And you did not explain what should happen if multiple entries are "close enough".

Comment: you are right, I provided a naive solution. Hoping for a more elegant implementation basically out of academic interest.

Comment: Such "how do I do this better?" questions are better suited to the Code Review site.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on Code Review.

Comment: @Scott You are just throuwing the OP in a catch 22 thing. " you should provide the way you tried to do it" . The OP then posts a naive way, it is the only way he can thnk of, nut he asking for a different approah altogether, you can't just say " now you have it working, so it is a code review question" .The OP intent is quite clear, and answers discussing different approaches to the problem belong here,

Comment: @Fuegon Do you test only one tuple at the time? If you can test multiple values, them you can use `heapq.merge` to merge the sets in linear time.